# Configurando SVN em Amazon EC2 - Não é solicitada a autenticação do usuário

Tags: linux, versionamento, svn, configuração

Estou com dificuldades para configurar o SVN em um servidor Amazon EC2 gerenciado pelo Bitnami. Na realidade criei essa máquina para utilizar o *Redmine*, mas também vou precisar do SVN.

Segui as instruções na wiki do *Bitnami* mas não consegui terminar o processo de configuração. Ao acessar meu repositório pelo browser ou mesmo pelo TortoiseSVN não é solicitado usuário e senha para realizar o acesso.

Está mais complicado porque esse servidor utiliza o *Ubuntu Linux 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit*, não tenho experiência com Linux e SVN. O que fiz até o momento:

- Criei o repositório:

  ```
  svnadmin create /home/bitnami/repositorio
  ```
- Editei o arquivo /home/bitnami/repositorio/svnserve.conf:

  ```
  [general]  
  anon-access = read  
  auth-access = write  
  password-db = passwd
  ```
- Adicionar meu usuário no arquivo `passwd`:

  ```
  [users]  
  meususario = minhasenha
  ```
- Reiniciei o serviço.
- Importei o projeto para o repositório:

  ```
  svn import /home/bitnami/projeto/ http://meudominio.bitnamiapp/repositorio/
  ```
- Adicionei este trecho ao arquivo de configuração do apache:

  ```
  LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so  
  LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so  
  LoadModule dav_svn_modulee modules/mod_dav_svn.so                                              
  LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so  

  < Location /repositorio >  
  DAV svn  
  SVNPath "/home/bitnami/repositorio/"  
  AuthType Basic  
  AuthName "Subversion repository"  
  AuthUserFile /opt/bitnami/repository/users  
  require valid-user  
  < /Location >
  ```
- Criei os usuários no apache:

  ```
  /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/htpasswd -c  /home/bitnami/repositorio/users newuser
  ```
- Ativei os commits via HTTP:

  ```
  sudo chown -R daemon:subversion /home/bitnami/repositorio
  ```

Apesar de eu conseguir acessar o repositório não é requerida autenticação
para acessar meu repositório. Será que eu pulei alguma etapa da configuração? Estou seguindo as orientações desta página: https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Subversion.

Outra dúvida, no Linux é normal o SVN criar um repositório sem a estrutura `/trunk /branches` e `/tags`? No Windows quando instalei foi criado automaticamente, então não sei se isso é normal ou mais um indício de que minha instalação está incorreta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não conheço praticamente nada dessa configuração, mas observando a linha:

> anon-access = read

Da sua configuração, tenho  impressão de que você ativou o modo de leitura para acesso anônimo, isto é, sem necessidade de senha.

Tente remover essa configuração ou deixá-la em branco.

Comment: Poxa @utluiz era isso mesmo. Uma vez alterado isso no arquivo svnserve.conf e reiniciados o subversion e o apache ele pediu os dados de autenticação. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @ArthurdeAndrade Legal! Bom que resolveu! Quanto à estrutura de diretórios, acho que não posso ajudar muito, mas talvez seja também questão de configuração.